# C# OpenGL problem with animation

Tags: c#, opengl

there is a program that simulates a small satellite and requires that a rotation animation of the satellite along the three axes. But when you try to write an animation problem during compilation: the program simply closes (shutdown occurs when swapbuffers, mainloop, redisplay), when you write the easiest programs have the same problem arose. Trying to catch exception by try-catch but here is not exception. How to solve this? I suffer with this a few days. Work in c# visual studio 2008 framework

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AnT1.InitializeContexts();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Glut.glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
            Glut.glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);
            Glut.glutMainLoop();
        }
    }
    void Timer(int Unused)
    {
        Glut.glutPostRedisplay();
        Glut.glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);
    }
        private void AnT1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Glut.glutInit();
        Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_RGB | Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);

        Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);

        Gl.glViewport(0, 0, AnT1.Width, AnT1.Height);


        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Glu.gluPerspective(45, (float)AnT1.Width / (float)AnT1.Height, 0.1, 200);
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();

        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glPushMatrix();

            double xy = 0.2;
            Gl.glTranslated(xy, 0, 0);
            xy += 0.2;
            Draw();
            Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
            Glut.glutPostRedisplay();
            Gl.glPushMatrix();
            Draw();
            Gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
    void Draw()
    {
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.7, 2, 60, 60);

        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutWireCylinder(0.7, 2, 20, 20);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What OpenGL library are you using?  OpenTK? SharpGL?

Comment: tao framework. partially i found my problem is glut library /: i can to animate simple 2d figures drawed by vertex without swapbuffers and mainloop

Answer (score 0):

You should move the statements in the `catch` block into `try` block.